# Resources for designing math degree programs

Tags: soft-question, education, career-development

I'd like to know where I can find resources which are helpful when one has to design or improve grad and undergrad degree programs in pure and applied mathematics.
In particular, I'm searching for up-to-date field studies containing data and/or analyses on career opportunities for math graduates who focused on dynamical systems and mathematical physics.

I know SIAM has released something of this kind, I'm searching some more material.

Just for clarity: I'm not necessarily asking for material released from Universities, rather for resources produced by international societies for the development of mathematics, governments, no-profit companies etc...

Thank you!

(I also asked this on Academia Stack Exchange, but someone suggested this is a better place)

Comment: Universities are now very much businesses and that would probably be regarded as commercially sensitive information these days. Such information may be hard to find.

Comment: Added some more information to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Another helpful place to ask would maybe be matheducators SE if you don't get an answer here.